# A way to pass a variable into a nested function

Tags: javascript

Is there a way i can pass information into a nested function ? The problem is i want to use jQuery to animate an object being removed and then after have it remove the object from the dom. But theres no way to pass information into the nested function. I first though the bellow would work but no luck,

```
tab = this.tab //this.tab is a dom element
$(this.tab).effect('drop',null,null, function(tab)
{
     $(tab).remove()
})
```

People have suggested that i store the element in a global put this function is part of a class and there can be many objects which may call this function at the same time.

Thankyou!

Comment: Doesn't `this` inside the closure refer to the object being animated? jQuery is quite clever in setting context, try `console.log`ging `this` inside the closure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using closures you should be able to simply do

```
var tab = this.tab
$(tab).effect('drop', null, null, function() { $(tab).remove(); });
```

Note that `tab` is defined outside the "nested function", but since JavaScript supports closures, the function can access variables defined in the same scope as itself. In other words, it'll be able to access `tab`.
Also note that it's *not* `this.tab`, since `this` refers to the context in which the code is called.

Addendum: I'm not a jQuery-guy (weird, I know), but I'd imagine that the function you pass to `effect()` will be executed in the `tab` element's context (i.e. inside the function `this` refers to the `tab` element). If so, you could probably just do

```
$(this.tab).effect('drop', null, null, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Comment: Thankyou for that ! JavaScripts scope does confuse me. Also im not normally a jQuery person, but when it comes to needing altra quick development the jQuery library is useful!